# Message passing Background.html -> Content Script

Tags: google-chrome-extension

I've got the following in my background.html to sendRequest to contentscript...

```
chrome.tabs.getSelected(null,function(tab)
    {
        chrome.tabs.sendRequest(tab.id,{req:"func"});
    });
```

However, it doesn't appear to be working. What am I doing wrong?

Portion of related manifest file...

```
 "background_page": "background.html",
"browser_action":
{
    "default_icon": "icon.png",
    "popup": "popup.html"
},
"permissions": [
    "tabs",
    "http://*/*",
    "https://*/*",
    "notifications",
    "contextMenus"
],
"options_page": "options.html",
"content_scripts": [
    {
        "matches": ["http://*/*","https://*/*"],
        "js": ["contentScript.js","jquery.js"],
        "all_frames": false
    }
],
```

contentscript...

```
    chrome.extension.onRequest.addListener(
 function(request, sender, sendResponse)
 {
switch(request.req)
{
        case "func":
        func();
        sendResponse({});
        break;
 default:
        sendResponse({});
 }
 });
```

Comment: Please show your manifest and request listener in a content script.

Comment: Did you put the code on your Background.html in a <script type='javascrip'> ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make this in the background page :

```
chrome.tabs.getSelected(null,function(tab)
{
    chrome.tabs.sendRequest(tab.id,{req:"func"}, function(response){
        alert(response.req); // Get The response
    });
});
```

And on the Content Script :

```
sendResponse({ req: 'Your Response' });
```

Also change your manifest to :

```
{
"background_page": "background.html",
"browser_action":
{
    "default_icon": "icon.png",
    "popup": "popup.html"
},
"permissions": [
    "tabs",
    "http://*/*",
    "https://*/*",
    "notifications",
    "contextMenus"
],
"options_page": "options.html",
"content_scripts": [
    {
        "matches": ["http://*/*","https://*/*"],
        "js": ["contentScript.js","jquery.js"],
        "all_frames": false
    }
],
"name" : "FirstExtension",
"version" : "1.0",
}
```

PS : Name and Version on the manifest are required...

Answer (score 0):

Your code runs fine for me. Probably a content script is not loaded on that page when you are sending the request. Do you have some sort of condition before `chrome.tabs.getSelected`? You can't just run it right away, you need to be sure that a tab is loaded first.

PS. Also in your manifest you probably would want to load jquery before your content script.